# Search tool in excel, vba

Tags: vba, excel

I'm novice in excel VBA and I really need help to extend my code.
The code searches for a text in all work sheets.
I would like to list all the search results in the first sheet with the complete row where the text is found. Unfortunately I don't know how to copy the row where the criteria is found.
Maybe if I can get a solution to inspect the code would be a great help.

```
Sub SearchAllSheets()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim rFound As Range
Dim strName As String

    On Error Resume Next
    strName = InputBox("What are you looking for?")
    If strName = "" Then Exit Sub
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        With ws.UsedRange
            Set rFound = .Find(What:=strName, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
            If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto rFound, True
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End With
    Next ws
    On Error GoTo 0

    MsgBox "Value not found"
```

End Sub

Comment: `rFound.Row` will be the rownumber and `rFound.EntireRow` will be the entire row so `rFound.EntireRow.Copy` will copy it... are you looking for something like that?

Comment: Can you please write me how is the loop looks like with copying the rows? Anyway, is my code a good approach for a search tool for listing the results?

Comment: You also could use the build-in search engine and use "search all". Isn't that all you need? (as long you are not going to copy countless rows) ^^;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you are looking to search a text for all the occurrences in all the sheets. Try this code:

```
Sub SearchAllSheets()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, OutputWs As Worksheet
    Dim rFound As Range, FirstAddress
    Dim strName As String
    Dim count As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim IsValueFound As Boolean

    IsValueFound = False
    Set OutputWs = Worksheets("Output")    '---->change the sheet name as required
    LastRow = OutputWs.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next
    strName = InputBox("What are you looking for?")
    If strName = "" Then Exit Sub
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Output" Then
            With ws.UsedRange
                Set rFound = .Find(What:=strName, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                    FirstAddress = rFound.Address

                    Do
                        Application.Goto rFound, True
                        IsValueFound = True
                        'MsgBox rFound.Row
                        Debug.Print rFound.Address

                        rFound.EntireRow.Copy
                        OutputWs.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                        Application.CutCopyMode = False
                        LastRow = LastRow + 1

                        Set rFound = .FindNext(rFound)
                    Loop While Not rFound Is Nothing And rFound.Address <> FirstAddress

                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next ws
    On Error GoTo 0
    If IsValueFound Then
       OutputWs.Select
       MsgBox "Result pasted to Sheet Output"
    Else
        MsgBox "Value not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Below code will paste the row with data found to sheet`Output`. Code will not search `Output` sheet for result.

```
Sub SearchAllSheets()        
    Dim ws As Worksheet, OutputWs As Worksheet
    Dim rFound As Range
    Dim strName As String
    Dim count As Long, LastRow As Long
    Dim IsValueFound As Boolean        

    IsValueFound = False
    Set OutputWs = Worksheets("Output")    '---->change the sheet name as required
    LastRow = OutputWs.Cells(Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    On Error Resume Next
    strName = InputBox("What are you looking for?")
    If strName = "" Then Exit Sub
    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Name <> "Output" Then
            With ws.UsedRange
                Set rFound = .Find(What:=strName, After:=.Cells(1, 1), LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
                If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
                    Application.Goto rFound, True
                    IsValueFound = True
                    'MsgBox rFound.Row
                    rFound.EntireRow.Copy
                    OutputWs.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
                    Application.CutCopyMode = False
                    LastRow = LastRow + 1
                End If
            End With
        End If
    Next ws
    On Error GoTo 0
    If IsValueFound Then
       OutputWs.Select
       MsgBox "Result pasted to Sheet Output"
    Else
        MsgBox "Value not found"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Exactly! Thank you very much.

Comment: While modifying the code a few problems occurred. In the code I changed the input method to a combobox and I pass the value to the string. So the user wont be able to make a misspell when enters the search criteria. On each worksheet the searched values are coming form a drop-down list. After the search the code only returns 1 value. Why?

Comment: @LórántCsabaMihály - can you provide code you've changed so that I can look into it.

Comment: @Mirg
I looked after it and the .Find method and it seems it only returns one value. So I have to loop it, but I think my loop is incorrect

`If Not rFound Is Nothing Then

Do While .Find = 0

Application.Goto rFound, True
IsValueFound = True
rFound.EntireRow.Cells(1, "B").Resize(1, 4).Copy
OutputWs.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Application.CutCopyMode = False
LastRow = LastRow + 1

Loop

End If`

Comment: @LórántCsabaMihály - What exactly do you mean by saying `I have to loop it`. Is .Find method not working properly?

Comment: @LórántCsabaMihály - See my new answer.